# XML Schema - xs:string - multiple occurrences

Tags: xml, string, xsd, xsd-validation

How should be formatted a given XML file to validate against the following schema?

```
...
<xs:element name="myElement">
 <xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3" name="myStringNode" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
...
```

Indeed, the constraints above describe that MyElement->stringNode must contain a string, which may occur multiple times. But what does that mean in case of multiple strings (3 or more)?

- Should be the enclosed strings separated by spaces, commas, ... or
  nothing?
- Has *maxOccurs* a real meaning?
- Should this XML validate/invalidate against the schema above?

  <myElement>
  <myStringNode>str1 str2 str3 str4 str5</myStringNode>
  </myElement>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it validates your example because "`str1 str2 ...`" is seen as a single string. If you want multiple `myStringNode` you just have to use multiple tags like :

```
<myElement>
     <myStringNode> here is your string </myStringNode>
     <myStringNode> here is your other string </myStringNode>
</myElement>
```

And `maxOccurs` specifies the number of element `<myStringNode>` you can add in an element `<myElement>`.